# How to receive automatic notifications when a new RunDeck version/patch is released?

Tags: rundeck

How can I register for notifications of **new patches** available for RunDeck via email (or any other means)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/news/feed.xml) RSS feed that notifies you of every new version. [Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/news/) the website.